# Remove optional whitespace when splitting with math operators while keeping them in the result

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, trim

How to remove whitespace characters from the input string? I am using the following code that

```
 Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim symbol As String = "([-+*/])"


    Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, symbol)
    Dim cleaned As String = Regex.Replace(input, "\s", " ")
    For Each match As String In substrings
        lstOutput.Items.Add(match)
    Next
```

Input: `z + x`

Output: `z`, `+` and  `x`.

I want to get rid of the whitespace in the last item.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) the input on space ?

Comment: @Sehnsucht: No, you cannot split with space because the space is optional on both sides of the operators. See [my](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%28%5b-%2b*%2f%5d%29%5cs*&i=z+%2b+x-+d) (yields `z`, `+`, `x`, `-`, `d`) and [your](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=+&i=z+%2b+x-+d) (yields `z`, `+`, `x-`, `d`) solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may remove the redundant whitespace while splitting with

```
\s*([-+*/])\s*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%28%5B-%2B*%2F%5D%29%5Cs*&i=z%20%2B%20x). Also, it is a good idea to trim the input before passing to the regex replace method with `.Trim()`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\s*` - matches 0+ whitespaces (these will be discarded from the result as they are not *captured*)
- `([-+*/])` - Group 1 (captured texts will be output to the resulting array) capturing 1 char: `-`, `+`, `*` or `/`
- `\s*` - matches 0+ whitespaces (these will be discarded from the result as they are not *captured*)

[image]

Comment: It worked but how about \s* - ibid can you explain what this stand for?  is it for closing for the first \s* or is it just to apply to the whole Group 1?

Comment: I meant "see above". Copied the explanation to the second occurrence of the subpattern.